# Do the members of a coven of hags still get their own spellcasting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

In 5e D&D, the coven of hags gets shared spellcasting. This enables them to cast spells with a shared amount of spell slots.

My question is, when they are not in the coven, aside from their own innate spellcasting, do they get their own spell slots?
I am using roll20 to source this information, and it details a spellbook at the bottom of the page, with all the spells a hag can cast - including the innate spellcasting and the coven spellcasting. This is the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, just the Innate Spellcasting ability (if that particular type of hag has that) which does not use slots. The spell slots are a special feature of the coven, and that feature specifically says it only works when all members of the coven are within 30 feet of each other.

I don't see anything about a spellbook — the hags do, however, have a limited list of spells, and it is perhaps an artifact of Roll20 that this list is presented as a spellbook.

The spells are described as being from the wizard spell list, and unlike the innate spellcasting, they're intelligence-based. If you, as a DM, decide to add wizard class levels to a hag following the guidance in the DMG, it would seem reasonable to put these spells in a spellbook. And even without that, a book with these spells seems like reasonable loot when defeating a coven, if you've got a spell-collecting wizard in the party.